# parseInt method for javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tried searching online why it does this. I tried changing the redix of the parseInt method but it doesn't seem to change anything as well.

```js
var sum = [6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 9, 5, 1, 8, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 4, 3]

// digits.length returns 19
var wholeNumber = sum.join("")
var makeNum = parseInt(wholeNumber)
console.log(wholeNumber) // returns string: 6145390195186705543
console.log(makeNum); // returns int: 6145390195186705000
```

Can anyone explain why **makeNum** does not return me the integer of ***wholeNumber*** but rather replaces the last 3 digits at the back with zeroes. I t

Comment: since that number is bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you could use `BigInt(wholeNumber)`

Comment: makeNum returns an array list that number is bigger than an int u need to rethink what ur doing u if u want the sum of the values or concatenate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is higher than the limit of an int. The max number you can use is `9007199254740991`
`6145390195186705543` is *way* larger.

Comment: is there a way then for me to make it into an integer? I want to subtract a number from it

Comment: For mathematical operations, or just for a string value?

Comment: Forgot we were talking JS. Derp. You can also use a library like big.js